# error are not logged but debug messages are logged

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using **codeignitor v.3.0-dev**.

In my `application\config\config.php` the following line

```
`$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` errors are not logging even if I place some wrong syntax's errors...
```

If I try

`$config['log_threshold'] = 2 or  3 or 4`  the messages are logged....

Can some one tell me why is this happening....

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Codeigniter  v.3? Are you sure? Where did you find that? I wasn't aware there was a v3. Also, are you saying that Debug messages are logged when you set it to `1`? They shouldn't be...

Comment: Also, parse errors can not be logged by codeignitor, because codeignitor isn't called, as PHP itself gives the fatal error.

Comment: Sorry for my english... hope its clear now

Comment: You mean only logical errors are logged...

Comment: HI guys from my research i found that CI logs all kinds of errors(including parse errors)... But in my case error was a Fatal error killing the process, so CI didnt log that error into the log file... Any corrections if i am wrong... Thank You...